# Android Address Book - Only show contacts white-listed by my app

Tags: android, addressbook

My app allows the user to white-list contacts. The user is allowed to make calls only to the white-listed contacts.

I have achieved this functionality by saving the white-listed contact information in a SQLite table and displaying them in an activity along with contact photo and name.

When the user clicks a contact, that contact card opens up and a call can be placed to the selected number.

**I would like to get rid of the activity that displays the white listed contacts and use the standard contacts app instead**.

The contacts app should display only those contacts that have been white listed by the user and hide the contacts that are *not* white-listed by the user.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: What you have done so far? Facing any issue??

Comment: I have edited your question to improve the grammar and layout to try and get more traction for answers.  Your questions is an interesting one, but it isn't a great fit for SO because it isn't focused on a specific issue you have hit while developing this solution and appears to be asking for a tutorial on the general concepts you will need to understand to achieve your solution.  Consider re-writing the question to give succinct code examples of exactly what you are having problems with.